# httpd.exe-The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005). Fix?

Tags: apache, wamp

First of all, im running a Windows 64bit OS. I was having WAMPServer 2 and all of the modules were running good. I knew about WAMPServer 3 and decided to upgrade to it. As of its documentation, we should uninstall the old version , requires all updated Visual C++ Redistributable Packages and i did it as it said.

Checked WAMPServer 3 requirements and also checked with their check_vcredist tool and the result was good. I installed WAMPServer 3, all other modules were working but Apache is not opening and throwing a error message-"The Application was unable to start correctly(0xc0000005)". Apache worked properly in WAMPServer 2.

If anyone's got a solution, please respond to the topic!

Comment: Look at the Windows Event Viewer  for error messages from Apache

Comment: Did you install both the 32bit and 64 bit MSVC Runtimes?

Comment: Yes i installed both

Answer (score 0):

Try using System Restore to restore your computer to an earlier successful time